# #include<vector> no such file or directory 2

Tags: c++, vector

I need to use vectors in my project.

```
#include <vector>
vector <wordStatistics> WORD_STATS[NUMBER_OF_LETTERS][NUMBER_OF_LETTERS];
```

and I have some errors.

> error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token

I`m using linux

Comment: Your file have the `.c` extension instead of `.cpp`. Do you use `g++` to compile ?

Comment: I,m sorry for writing error

Comment: Try changing `vector`by `std::vector`since `vector` is in the `std`namespace or do you have `using namespace std;` somewhere ?

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about the "no such file or directory" error. Did the question change? (If the question changes completely, it's usually better to post a new one. In this case, you should probably edit the title)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you compile as c++ (standard for `.cpp` extensions).

Here's a free hint:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector <wordStatistics> WORD_STATS(NUMBER_OF_LETTERS);
```

It doesn't make much sense to use a C-style array of vectors and it is likely not what you wanted.
Instead, this creates a single vector with `NUMBER_OF_LETTER` elements.